# What is the purpose of using #define to define a constant with no value?

Tags: preprocessor

What is the purpose of using #define to define a constant with no value?

Such as:

`#define TOKEN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it to enable or disable certain code using `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`, eg this:

```
#ifdef TOKEN
    printf("token is defined");
#endif
```

One use for this would be to toggle logging in debug builds. Another would be [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 0):

As @Nutomic says, this sort of `#define` is useful for enabling/disabling certain bits of code. I've seen this used to create compile-time options for a given library:

```
#ifdef STRICT_PARSING
  //...
#endif

#ifdef APPROXIMATE_PARSING
  //...
#endif

#ifdef UNICODE //this is especially useful when trying to control Unicode vs ANSI builds
  //call Unicode functions here
#else
  //call Ansi functions here
#endif

#ifdef USE_STL //another good one, used to activate or deactivate STL-based bits of an API; the function declarations were dependent on USE_STL being defined. A plain-C API was exposed either way, but the STL support was nice too.
  std::string MyApi();
#endif
```